# Send python string using vb6 winsock

Tags: python, vb6, winsock, basic

I assume I don't know python. This script sends a simple string over lan to a lan address (from my pc to a python server)

```
-------------------------------------------------------
    import socket
#
host ="192.168.0.17"
port =49280
#
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
#
s.sendall("set MIXER:Current/InCh/Fader/On 1 0 1\n".encode())
s.recv(1500)
s.close
-----------------------------------------------
```

I would like to send the same string but using vb6....

```
--------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Command3_Click()
Winsock1.RemoteHost = "192.168.0.17"
Winsock1.RemotePort = 49280
Winsock1.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol
Winsock1.Connect
winsock1

  Dim stringa1, stringa As String
  Dim Data() As Byte
  stringa = "set MIXER:Current/InCh/Fader/On 1 0 1\n"
  Data = StrConv(stringa, vbFromUnicode)
  
    Winsock1.SendData Data

End Sub
----------------------------------------------
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.
With the first script, my remote python server responds correctly, with the script in vb6 the server shows no signs of life
Anyone can tell me what mistake I make? thanks to all and good continuation
Mario

Comment: VB6 isn't a scripting language.  If you want to send ANSI characters you can skip the Byte array and explicit conversion, Just send the String data.  You have no code to await and accept returned response data.  And what is the Variant `stringa1` for anyway?  But your core problem may be silly use of C syntax to try to escape a linefeed character.

Comment: Hi Bob, "string1" is just a variable that was included in the original script and had other purposes not related to sending the data. It remained written but is not needed for this purpose. I had already tried to send the string first, simply, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon this table:

https://www.quackit.com/python/reference/python_3_escape_sequences.cfm

a `\n` in Python is a line feed. So in VB6 that would be `vbLf`.

So try changing your line to this:

`stringa = "set MIXER:Current/InCh/Fader/On 1 0 1" & vbLf`

Comment: I think the Byte() conversion is still needed, as Python's `string.encode()` method seems to [convert a string to bytes](https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/send), which is what the `socket.send()` method sends: "The data to be sent in bytes. In case the data is in string format, the encode() method of str can be called to convert it into bytes."

Comment: Yeah, there was nothing wrong with the `StrConv` call. I actually think that the winsock control would probably have done that internally so I bet it would work with or without that. In any case, the device that is receiving the message is almost certainly looking for the end of line and that is why the original code was not working.

Comment: Even a cursory reading of the documentation would tell you that sending a String always invokes conversion to ANSI.